# How to say unpredictable in Japanese

Tags: phrase-requests

I'd like to say "I like anime because its unpredictable". I found out through searching online that ありきたり translates to predictable, however I'm not sure if this is correct.

My entire sentence:

> いっぱんにアニメとまんがのものがたりはたのしいですとおもいます。なぜなら、いつもありきたりでわありません。

My second question would be, does いっぱんに translate to generally in the way I've used it above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common way that people phrase this is by saying "don't know what will happen next". Using the most basic vocab, I will say something like

> アニメと[漫画]{まんが}は、次｛つぎ｝に何｛なに｝が起｛お｝こるか分｛わ｝かりませんから、楽｛たの｝しいと思｛おも｝います。

次 means next, and 起こる/起こります means to occur (not to be confused with 起｛お｝きます).

Edit: to clarify, both 起きる and 起こる are acceptable usages. In fact, [upon further research](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%B5%B7%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B), 起きる is a more common way to say it.

Comment: `not to be confused with 起きます` -- But you can say both 「事件が起きる」and「事件が起こる」,「何が起こるかわからない」 and 「何が起きるかわからない」, 「アニメや漫画は、次に何が起こるか or 起きるかわからないから・・・」

Comment: @Chocolate Yes, 起きます is taught in (at least my) intro textbook as waking up, so I just wanted to point out it might be different than the way a beginner might have already seen the word.

Answer (score -1):

I can't really tell you on the nuances and stuff of your sentence, but what I can say for certain is that you should cut the です in front of the とおもいます.
When です is used with i-Adjectives, its purpose is to make the expression polite (you can think of it as a replacement for the ~ます-form). Unlike in English, the "is"-part of the adjective is pretty much already included in the plain form (i.e. how they appear in the dictionary) of i-Adjectives. So you can think of たのしい as "is funny". And since quotative と most of the time uses the plain form in front of it, たのしいとおもいます is better in this case.

Comment: It seems like my post wasn't recieved well. I'd like to improve, so I would appreciate it if someone could tell me the reason for it. Was it because I didn't really answer the user's question, or was it because of some grammatical error in my post?